# Disable Laravel's Eloquent timestamps

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm in the process of converting one of our web applications from CodeIgniter to Laravel. However at this moment we don't want to add the `updated_at` / `created_at` fields to all of our tables as we have a logging class that does all this in more depth for us already.

I'm aware I can set `$timestamps = false;` in:

```
Vendor\laravel\framework\src\illuminate\Datebase\Eloquent\Model.php
```

However I'd rather not change a core file for Laravel, or have everyone of my models have that at the top. Is there any way to disable this elsewhere for all models?

Answer (score 521, accepted):

You either have to declare `public $timestamps = false;` in every model, or create a BaseModel, define it there, and have all your models extend it instead of eloquent.  Just bare in mind pivot tables MUST have timestamps if you're using Eloquent.

Update: Note that timestamps are no longer REQUIRED in pivot tables after Laravel v3.

Update: You can also disable timestamps by removing `$table->timestamps()` from your migration.

Comment: Don't know why I never thought of doing a BaseModel and setting it there. Works beautifully. Just a note according to the documentation pivot tables need it only if setting withTimestamps() now (don't know if this changed from previous versions)

Comment: Wasn't aware of the withTimestamps() method.  I'll need to look into it.

Comment: @bgallagh3r, is there anyway to diasble only for perticuler query , Lets say for fontend display i dont want timestamp, but for backend i want time stamp. 
Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: When removing $table->timestamps() from the migration, eloquent will still include them in the query. This leads to an error as the field does not exists. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: Yes, this is still the case today (Laravel Framework v7.22.4). Found this thread trying to work around this issue. You have to explicitely disable the timestamps via `$timestamps = false;` to, e.g., seed a table that doesn't have any `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

Comment: Creating a BaseModel is very good. As an added bonus, it allows, if one needs to use singular name tables (among other things) to redefine the database table naming strategy by redefining the getTable() method.

Comment: Noob question: does it need to be public? All other variables in the model are of the protected type.

Answer (score 218):

**Simply place this line in your Model**:

`public $timestamps = false;`

And that's it!

---

*Example:*

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    //
}
```

---

To disable timestamps **for one operation** (e.g. in a controller):

```
$post->content = 'Your content'; 
$post->timestamps = false; // Will not modify the timestamps on save
$post->save();
```

---

To disable timestamps **for all of your Models**, create a new `BaseModel` file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BaseModel extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    //
}
```

Then extend each one of your Models with the `BaseModel`, like so:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Post extends BaseModel
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 52):

**If you are using 5.5.x:**

```
const UPDATED_AT = null;
```

And for 'created_at' field, you can use:

```
const CREATED_AT = null;
```

Make sure you are on the newest version.
(This was broken in Laravel 5.5.0 and fixed again in 5.5.5).

**Update: Now (Laravel 8+) you can use timestamp('cloumn_name') to specify the column name. It only creates one column.**

```
$table->timestamp('cloumn_name');
```

Also, you can use the following format to auto-fill by the current timestamp.

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
```

Answer (score 25):

If you only need to only to disable updating updated_at just add this method to your model.

```
public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    // to Disable updated_at
}
```

This will override the parent setUpdatedAtAttribute() method. created_at will work as usual.
Same way you can write a method to disable updating created_at only.

Comment: This worked for me because setting $timestamps = false caused created_at->diffForHumans() method to stop working since it's no longer a carbon instance.

Comment: It works for me, this method just disable the updated_at field that I need, thanks

Answer (score 19):

In case you want to remove timestamps from existing model, as mentioned before, place this in your Model:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Also create a migration with following code in the `up()` method and run it:

```
Schema::table('your_model_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropTimestamps();
});
```

You can use `$table->timestamps()` in your `down()` method to allow rolling back.

Comment: This should be the best answer. If you have an existing production database, you'd need to run a migration as well as disable timestamps on the model.

Answer (score 16):

**Eloquent Model:**

```
class User extends Model    
{      
    protected $table = 'users';

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**Or Simply try this**

```
$users = new Users();
$users->timestamps = false;
$users->name = 'John Doe';
$users->email = 'johndoe@example.com';
$users->save();
```

Answer (score 13):

Add this line into your model:

> Overwrite existing variable `$timestamps` **true** to **false**

```php
/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 */

public $timestamps = false;
```

Answer (score 8):

just declare the `public` timestamps variable in your `Model` to `false` and everything will work great.

`public $timestamps = false;`

Answer (score 4):

Override the functions `setUpdatedAt()` and `getUpdatedAtColumn()` in your model

```
public function setUpdatedAt($value)
{
   //Do-nothing
}

public function getUpdatedAtColumn()
{
    //Do-nothing
}
```

Comment: A case of "it works but no-one in their right mind would actually do this"

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily disable timestamps

```
$timestamps = $user->timestamps;
$user->timestamps=false;   // avoid view updating the timestamp

$user->last_logged_in_at = now();
$user->save();

$user->timestamps=$timestamps;   // restore timestamps
```

Answer (score 2):

just use this code on your model

```
 protected $hidden = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
];
```

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.