# How to get rid of error Unknown column updated_at when table timestamps() was removed

Tags: database, laravel

I have these two functions.When I try to insert data I get this error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;updated_at&#039
```

So it keeps searching for 'created at' and 'updated at' tables, but I've got rid of it before and replaced it with 'joined' and 'leaved'. How to fix it?

In BroadcastServiceProvider

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
        $ip = Request::ip();
        $time = now();        
        if (auth()->check() && !session()->has('name'))  { 
            UserInfo::storeUser();
            session()->put('name',$user->name);
            return [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'ip' => $ip,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'joined' => $time,
            ];
        }
    });
```

Schema

```
   Schema::create('user_info', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('ip');
        $table->string('joined');
        $table->string('leaved');
    });
```

In LoginController

```
 public function logout() {
    auth()->logout();
    session()->forget('name');
    session()->put('leaved',now());
       return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: public $timestamps = false;

Comment: Put this thing in model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Laravel's Eloquent timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937565/disable-laravels-eloquent-timestamps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Eloquent expects `created_at` and `updated_at` columns to exist on your tables.

If you do not wish to have these columns automatically managed by Eloquent, set the `$timestamps` property on your model to `false`:

```
/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $timestamps = false;
```

If you need to customize the names of the columns used to store the timestamps, you may set the `CREATED_AT` and `UPDATED_AT` constants in your model:

```
const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date';
const UPDATED_AT = 'last_update';
```

**See also:**

[Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Answer (score 3):

What you need, is to add to the model **UserInfo** the following:

```
public $timestamps = false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Add this code in Model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is model structure in laravel where you can add timestamps to be false.

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class modelName extends Model    
    {      
        protected $table = 'tableName';

        public $timestamps = false; //add this line
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel offers a better way to **MUTE** some particular fields in your table schema. For your case the correct way to remove the created at and the updated at columns in your table would be to do so in the Model itself rather than commenting out the timestamps in the migration file.

In the model for you can **MUTE** the timestamps as shown below :

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

This prevents the `created_at` and the `updated_at` columns not to be created while running migrations.

In the event you want to reuse the `updated_at` and the `created_at` column by renaming them, then you can do so still in the model as :

```
const CREATED_AT = 'joined_at';
const UPDATED_AT = 'logged_out_at';
```

Modifying defaults traits in laravel model :

> https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent