Laravel disable timestamps in pivot tables
I use a pivot table for the relation between product and shipping class.
How I can tell laravel that the pivot table doesn't have timestamps?
class Product {
    public function shippingClass(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(ShippingClass::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}

class ShippingClass extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
    ];

    public function products(): HasMany{
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}

pivot:
Schema::create('product_shipping_class', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->primary();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('shipping_class_id');

        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('shipping_class_id')->references('id')->on('shipping_classes')->onDelete('cascade');
    });


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937565/disable-laravels-eloquent-timestamps
